# Error when building OpenCV on my mac: 'Py_ssize_t' issues

Tags: build, opencv

I've been following the instructions here: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port, and have just finished the make -j8 step.  Although the make completes to 100%, I am getting errors

```
make[2]: *** [interfaces/python/CMakeFiles/cvpy.dir/cv.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [interfaces/python/CMakeFiles/cvpy.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Specific errors I see in the stack trace are all from a file called cv.cpp:

```
/other/open_cv/opencv/opencv/interfaces/python/cv.cpp:18: error: ‘Py_ssize_t’ does not    name a type
/other/open_cv/opencv/opencv/interfaces/python/cv.cpp:206: error: ‘Py_ssize_t’ does not name a type
/other/open_cv/opencv/opencv/interfaces/python/cv.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* iplimage_tostring(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
/other/open_cv/opencv/opencv/interfaces/python/cv.cpp:282: error: ‘what_size’ was not declared in this scope
/other/open_cv/opencv/opencv/interfaces/python/cv.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* cvmat_tostring(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
/other/open_cv/opencv/opencv/interfaces/python/cv.cpp:425: error: ‘what_size’ was not declared in this scope
```

(which continues for a long while).  I followed all of the steps and am not sure where I am going wrong.  Any help for installing open cv on my mac (Snow Leopard)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an old version of python (MacPython was overriding the default python version).  Just get rid of MacPython, and you are good to go.

Comment: What exactly does "get rid of MacPython" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the most recent svn from the repository.
I could not get the tar ball to build but the svn check out built correctly
"https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv"
You will also need the OpenCV.framework for xcode to build the app with.
I found this page to have the best info to get openCV working on an Mac
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port
So far I have only got this to work on an intel based Mac.